# Sharepoint 2010 External List Image column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, external-content-type, external-list

I have a SQL table with 5 columns in it (EmployeeName, StartDt, EndDt, Location, PictureUrl). I want to display this data in a Sharepoint List. I want the image to be displayed in my sharepoint list's "PictureUrl" column based on the url in the external location.

How to solve this?

Comment: did you saw this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/543b0ca6-7626-4132-baf3-46b485cc82ad/insert-image-column-in-external-content-type?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Answer (score 2):

You can use a content query web part. Then customize it in such a way it can be set to display image instead of the url. I am not sure whether you can customize the entire External List. When you are using the Content query Web Part you can customize the XSLT in it. There then set it to view the image instead of url.

Comment: External Lists are not supported by content query webpart.

Comment: But you can create a custom list, then add a External Data Column, include the url field with it, then use it in CQWP.